# Двусмысленные метки - это допустимо или нет?

Tags: обсуждение, метки

В ленте увидел вопрос с меткой "ссылка". Вот сам вопрос [(ссылка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1160504/212981)

Перейдя к вопросам с меткой "ссылка" можно увидеть вопросы не только о так называемой ***"гиперссылке"***, но также и вопросы о ссылке как ***значении адреса в памяти***, по которым находятся какие-то данные. Получается, что метка имеет два смысла. Мне кажется, это не очень удобно для тех, кто ищет вопросы по меткам. Стоит ли что-то делать в такой ситуации? Я думаю, стоит как-то разделить эту метку на две:

- Ссылка
- Гиперссылка

Comment: Согласен, в данном случае стоит разделить

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Надо разделять.

В свое время (уже давненько...) проявил инициативу и добавил к "шаблоны", которые и тогда были описаны как шаблоны проектирования, метку "шаблоны-с++". Перерыл все вопросы с меткой, исправил...

Все равно и сейчас постоянно вынужден время от времени проходить и менять неверно поставленную метку "шаблоны" вместо "шаблоны-с++".

Кстати, сейчас проверил - опять три таких вопроса...

Я к тому, что как ни дели, как ни описывай - все равно, если метку можно использовать неправильно - будут находиться те, кто будет ее использовать неправильно.

Мало взять на себя инициативу как-то изменить метки - надо брать на себя еще и исправление неверно поставленных меток.

Answer (score 5):

- Теоретически метки должны иметь только один смысл
- Довольно часто возникают неоднозначные метки, которые пытаются разделять
- Когда разделение совсем не взлетает, на это официально забивают и решают [использовать одну для всего](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319591/4928642)